# I want to add text on 3d boxes but i cant see them

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I want to add text on 3d boxes but i cant see them, when i rotate camera, i can see but, it looks like remains inside of box. how can see show them front of box? should i make boxes transparent or something?

you can see "li" on left.

[image]

but it should shown like this :
[image]

( stopped creation of box when create 1st)

summary is:

```py
  xz_sizes = np.array(boyutlar)
        
        xz_sizes[:,1] = 0
        
        print(xz_sizes)
        label_pos = (np.array(pozisyon) + xz_sizes/2 ).tolist()
        labels = ["limegreen","blue","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

        # labels = ['12', '24']
        for pos, label in zip(label_pos, labels):
            axGlob.text( *pos, label, 'x', ha='center', va='center') 
            counter2 += 2
            if counter2 == 100:
                break
```

```py
Fullcode=class Painter:

    def __init__(self,bins):
        self.items = bins.items
        self.width = bins.width
        self.height = bins.height
        self.depth = bins.depth

    def _plotCube(self, ax, x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color='red',mode=2):
        # stoppause = 5
        """ Auxiliary function to plot a cube. code taken somewhere from the web.  """
        xx = [x, x, x+dx, x+dx, x]
        yy = [y, y+dy, y+dy, y, y]
        
        kwargs = {'alpha': 1, 'color': color,'linewidth':1 }
        if mode == 1 :
            ax.plot3D(xx, yy, [z]*5, **kwargs)
            ax.plot3D(xx, yy, [z+dz]*5, **kwargs)
            ax.plot3D([x, x], [y, y], [z, z+dz], **kwargs)
            ax.plot3D([x, x], [y+dy, y+dy], [z, z+dz], **kwargs)
            ax.plot3D([x+dx, x+dx], [y+dy, y+dy], [z, z+dz], **kwargs)
            ax.plot3D([x+dx, x+dx], [y, y], [z, z+dz], **kwargs)
        else :
            text='sadsadas'
            p = Rectangle((x,y),dx,dy,fc=color,ec='black')
           
            p2 = Rectangle((x,y),dx,dy,fc=color,ec='black',label = 'adad')
            p3 = Rectangle((y,z),dy,dz,fc=color,ec='black')
            p4 = Rectangle((y,z),dy,dz,fc=color,ec='black')
            p5 = Rectangle((x,z),dx,dz,fc=color,ec='black')
            p6 = Rectangle((x,z),dx,dz,fc=color,ec='black')
            ax.add_patch(p)
           # ax.annotate(text, (x+dx/2,y))
            ax.add_patch(p2)
           # ax.annotate(text, (x+dx/2,y))
            ax.add_patch(p3)
            ax.add_patch(p4)
            ax.add_patch(p5)
            ax.add_patch(p6)
           # ax.text(x+dx, y+dy/2, z, "red", color='red',rotation_mode= None,verticalalignment = 'top',animated = 'b')
            # ax.text
            ax.annotate(text, (x,y))
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=z, zdir="z")
            # art3d.text(x+0.8,y+0.8,z+0.8, 'label', zdir="x")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p2, z=z+dz, zdir="z")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p3, z=x, zdir="x")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p4, z=x + dx, zdir="x")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p5, z=y, zdir="y")
            art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p6, z=y + dy, zdir="y")

    
        
    def plotBoxAndItems(self,title=""):
        counter2 = 0
        with open('boyutlar.csv', newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            boyutlar = list(reader)
          
        boyutlar = [e for e in boyutlar if e]

        # boyutlar = [[float(value) for value in sublist] for sublist in boyutlar]      
        boyutlar = [list(map(float, y)) for y in boyutlar]         
              
        with open('pozisyon.csv', newline='') as f:
            reader2 = csv.reader(f)
            pozisyon = list(reader2)
        pozisyon = [e for e in pozisyon if e]
        # print(pozisyon)

        # pozisyon = [[float(value) for value in sublist] for sublist in pozisyon]   
        pozisyon = [[float(value) for value in sublist] for sublist in pozisyon]
        print(pozisyon)
        
        """ side effective. Plot the Bin and the items it contains. """
        fig = plt.figure()
        axGlob = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        stoppause = 1
        counter=0
        # fit rotation type
        for item in self.items:
            rt = item.rotation_type  
            x,y,z = item.position
            [w,h,d] = item.getDimension()
            color = item.color
            # countt=countt+1
            if item.typeof == 'cube':
                 # plot item of cube
                self._plotCube(axGlob, float(x), float(y), float(z), float(w),float(h),float(d),color=color,mode=2)
            elif item.typeof == 'cylinder':
                # plot item of cylinder
                self._plotCylinder(axGlob, float(x), float(y), float(z), float(w),float(h),float(d),color=color,mode=2)
            
            counter = counter + 1 
            if counter == stoppause:
                break
        # plot bin 
        self._plotCube(axGlob,0, 0, 0, float(self.width), float(self.height), float(self.depth),color='black',mode=1)
        
        plt.title('result')
        self.setAxesEqual(axGlob)
        xz_sizes = np.array(boyutlar)
        
        xz_sizes[:,1] = 0
        
        print(xz_sizes)
        label_pos = (np.array(pozisyon) + xz_sizes/2 ).tolist()
        labels = ["limegreen","blue","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

        # labels = ['12', '24']
        for pos, label in zip(label_pos, labels):
            axGlob.text( *pos, label, 'x', ha='center', va='center') 
            counter2 += 1
            if counter2 == 1:
                break

        plt.show()
```